# Rotation's effect on background image

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimage

I would like the background image of a view to change every time there's rotation. The image changes, yet when the rotation is horizontal, it cuts it off as if it were a portrait image. Here's what I mean: [image]

This orientation is horizontal, yet the image is cropped for portrait dimensions. The [actual image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vm9hqx5n0grt65j/H0.png) is fit to be horizontal.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
// called after rotation occurs

if (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
    // now horizontal
    imageToLoad = [UIImage imageNamed:@"H0.png"];
} else {
    // now portrait
    imageToLoad = [UIImage imageNamed:@"P0.png"];
}
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[imageToLoad drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
}
```

How could I solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: The code looks fine unless you're doing something weird before & after this. :) 
can this me due to a cached image perhaps with the wrong name you had before ?
try cleaning build directory & see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why use background color? Add a `UIImageView` with appropriate autoresizing mask and content mode.

Comment: I used an image view for this purpose before, and it's substantially harder to deal with for resizing upon rotation.